# What is the meaning of the logger name in .NET common logging?

Tags: .net, logging

I'm using the [.NET common logging infrastructure V2.0](http://netcommon.sourceforge.net/). I'm getting an ILog object like so:

```
ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger("myLogName");
```

and I don't understand the meaning and effect of the log name. **Does it matter if I use the same name all over the process**, or can i just use `LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()` for every class (yes, I know comes with a performance penalty).

p.s:
I will probably use log4net & ConsoleOutLogger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe name means whatever you want it to mean. There are two main reasons for using distinct names in different places:

- You can configure logging for just that logger (e.g. turn up the log level for a particular area of code if you're investigating a problem in it)
- You can easily see the area of code from the name, so your messages are effectively already scoped.

Comment: Thanks Jon. But I didn't found a way to change log level for a certain log name by configuration. How it can be done?

Comment: It's something that you do in log4net and not in common.logging. As it's a implementation specific detail.

Answer (score 0):

Please see GetLogger implementation below. Name is specific of concrete logger.

```
public sealed class LogManager
{
    ...
    public static ILoggerFactoryAdapter Adapter { get; set; }

    public static ILog GetLogger(string name)
    {
        return Adapter.GetLogger(name); // Adapter is  ILoggerFactoryAdapter
    }
}

public interface ILoggerFactoryAdapter
{
    // Methods
    ILog GetLogger(string name);
    ILog GetLogger(Type type);
}
```

For log4net adapter implementation looks like this

```
public class Log4NetLoggerFactoryAdapter : ILoggerFactoryAdapter
{
  ...
  public ILog GetLogger(string name)
  {
    return new Log4NetLogger(LogManager.GetLogger(name)); // LogManager - is log4net.Logmanager
  }
}
```